# why my desired string is not replacing with another in javascript?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have this `string`

```
content = 'Hi John Doe,

Your appointment has been scheduled for 30-Mar-20 at 05:00 pm.  
Please confirm your appointment. [link]'

confirmationTagsArray = [
  {tag : '[customer_name]' : value : 'John Doe'},
  {tag : '[startDate]' : value : '30-Mar-20'},
  {tag : '[start_time]' : value : '05:00 pm'},
];
```

Here is my function to replace strings

```
  parseBackConfirmationText() {
   let str = this.content;
   this.confirmationTagsArray.forEach(tag => {
     if (str.includes(tag.value)) {
      str.replace(tag.value, tag.tag);
     }
   });
   return str;
  }
```

In this f`unction` i am replacing some `strings` with another strings in a loop. But it's not replacing the strings. It returns me the same string that i provided like this

```
Hi John Doe,

Your appointment has been scheduled for 30-Mar-20 at 05:00 pm.  
Please confirm your appointment. [link]
```

But it should return like this

```
Hi [customer_name],

Your appointment has been scheduled for [start_date] at [start_time].  
Please confirm your appointment. [link]
```

What am i doing wrong?

Comment: Please create a small demo for this and post in your queestion.

Comment: `str.replace(tag.value, tag.tag);` should be `str = str.replace(tag.value, tag.tag);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have few issues in your code:

1. Your object is syntactically invalid.
2. You have to declare the function with *function* keyword.
3. `replace()` does not modify the the original string, you have to reassign the modified string to the variable.

Try the following way:

```js
content = `Hi John Doe,

Your appointment has been scheduled for 30-Mar-20 at 05:00 pm.  
Please confirm your appointment. [link]`

confirmationTagsArray = [
  {tag : '[customer_name]', value : 'John Doe'},
  {tag : '[startDate]', value : '30-Mar-20'},
  {tag : '[start_time]', value : '05:00 pm'},
];

function parseBackConfirmationText() {
 let str = content;
 confirmationTagsArray.forEach(tag => {
   if (str.includes(tag.value)) {
    str = str.replace(tag.value, tag.tag);
   }
 });
 return str;
}
console.log(parseBackConfirmationText());
```

Comment: I am using angular so no need of declare function with function keyword. Anyway your answer helped me out. Thanx.